# Correct way to serialized in custome editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is test script

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int something;
}
```

**1.if i directly set the value without use serializedProperty**

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestEditor : Editor
{
    private Test test;
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        test = target as Test;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        test.something = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Something", test.something);

        if (GUI.changed)
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
    }
}
```

value is saved successfully in editor

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AomyP.gif)

but if i restart unity,the value will be reset,this means the value is not serialized to disk?

**2.if use serializedProperty**

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        
        var something = serializedObject.FindProperty("something");
        something.intValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Something", something.intValue);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

everything is right

**my question**

why first way can save value in editor but not serilized to disk? is my script something wrong?

what's the true difference bewtween them?

second way is the correct way to serilized?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **SerializedProperty** class for editing properties on objects in a completely generic way that automatically handles undo and styling UI for Prefabs.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestEditor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty something;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        /* Fetch the objects from the GameObject script to display in the inspector */
        something = serializedObject.FindProperty("something");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        /* Update the serializedProperty - always do this in the beginning of OnInspectorGUI. */
        serializedObject.Update();
        /* Display your field in the inspector */
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(something);
        /* Apply changes to the serializedProperty - always do this in the end of OnInspectorGUI. */
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```